# is it possible to add new string to existing string in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have variable newValue and javascript object

```
 var newValue = value3;
 var myJson = 
 {
    key1 : value3
    key2 : [ value1,value2] 
 }
```

I want to add the variable newValue( value3) to key2 in the myjson meaning to the array.

```
       key2 : [value1,value2,value3]
```

also it is possible that the key2 will be empty and then i need to add array with the newvalue meaning

```
   keys : [ value3]
```

I did it with string logic but I want to di it with regular expression is it possible with regular expression?

Comment: Can you elaborate? It's hard to tell what you're asking; the code you posted isn't even correct.

Comment: *"I did it with string logic"* - Please show your existing code so that we can better see what you're trying to do. The normal way to do this is *not* to manipulate JSON as a string, but to parse it to get an object, modify that object, and then convert back to JSON. (Although your edit now shows that you don't have JSON, you already have an object, so I'm at a bit of a loss as to how you modified it with "string logic".)

Comment: Right - to be clear, there is no JSON involved in the code posted. That's just a JavaScript object literal; it would be invalid as JSON.

Comment: sorry it is o bject not a josn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `myJson` variable is a reference to an object, not to JSON (JSON is a string format). So your talk of using "string logic" or regular expressions to manipulate it don't make any sense.

To add a value to the array that `key2` refers to you can do this:

```
myJson.key2.push(newValue);
```

UPDATE to go with your latest edit:

> *"also it is possible that the `key2` will be empty and then i need to add array with the newvalue meaning"*

If you mean that `key2` might not even exist then test for that first and create it as an empty array if needed:

```
if (!myJson.hasOwnProperty("key2"))
   myJson.key2 = [];
myJson.key2.push(newValue);
```